# Determining session ID from WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to run WebDriverJS on the browser, but the documentation is somewhat vague on how to get it controlling the host browser.  Here, it says:

> Launching a browser to run a WebDriver test against another browser is a tad redundant 
>   (compared to simply using node). Instead, using WebDriverJS in the browser is intended for 
>   automating the browser actually running the script. This can be accomplished as long as the > URL for the server and session ID for the browser are known. While these values may be 
>   passed to the builder directly, they may also be defined using the wdurl and wdsid 
>   "environment variables", which are parsed from the loading page's URL query data:

```
    <!-- Assuming HTML URL is /test.html?wdurl=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub&wdsid=foo1234 -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src="webdriver.js"></script>
    <input id="input" type="text"/>
    <script>
      // Attaches to the server and session controlling this browser.
      var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();

      var input = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('input'));
      input.sendKeys('foo bar baz').then(function() {
        assertEquals('foo bar baz',
            document.getElementById('input').value);
      });
    </script>
```

I want to open up my test page from Node.js, and then run the commands included in the client-side script.  However, I don't know how I would be able to extract the session ID (wdsid query parameter) when I build the session.  Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out after a lot of experimentation and reading through the WebDriverJS source code.

```
var webdriver = require('./assets/webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities({
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'version': '',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'javascriptEnabled': true
    }).
    build();

var testUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/test',
    hubUrl = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    sessionId;

driver.session_.then(function(sessionData) {
    sessionId = sessionData.id;
    driver.get(testUrl + '?wdurl=' + hubUrl + '&wdsid=' + sessionId);
});
```

driver.session_ returns a Promise object which will contain the session data and other information upon instantiation.  Using .then(callback(sessionData)) will allow you to manipulate the data as you wish.

Comment: If this did work at one point, it does not appear so now.  I'm seeing it's been moved to sessionData.id_

Answer (score 1):

My Selenium version: 4.1.0

Get sesion_id with `await`

```
const get_session_id = async (SeleniumDriver) =>
{
    const res1 = await SeleniumDriver.getSession();
    return res1.getId();
}
```

call in other function:
`await get_session_id(SeleniumDriver);`